# Android Canvas Rotated Text with Typeface not saved properly on SD card

Tags: android, fonts, android-canvas, truetype, typeface

I am drawing rotated text on canvas and then saving it to SD card as JPEG.
The problem I am facing is the canvas preview looks fine, but the rotated text in the saved image is not coming properly. When I use the default Android fonts, the final JPEG is the same as the canvas preview, but this code doesn't work for a custom typeface.

[I have uploaded both the final saved image and screenshot of canvas preview](http://www.flickr.com/photos/87489159@N06/)

I am using a custom view class for canvas drawing, here is my code

```
public class MyBringBack extends View {


    Bitmap bitmap;
    Typeface type;

public MyBringBack(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/rockwell-bold.ttf"); 
         setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);



    Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       // paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
        paint.setTextSize(23);
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
        paint1.setTextSize(40);
        paint1.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.rotate(90,434,110);
        canvas.drawText("Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text  ", 434, 110, paint);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        paint1.setTypeface(type);
        canvas.rotate(90,130,185);
        canvas.drawText("Text using Typeface ", 130, 185, paint1);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(90,180,185);
        canvas.drawText("Text using Typeface ",180, 185, paint1);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(90,230,185);
        canvas.drawText("Text using Typeface ", 230, 185, paint1);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.save();

        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap c= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.getDrawingCache(), canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(), false);

        /* Saving File To SD Card   */

        OutputStream outStream = null;
        File bgv = new File("/sdcard/");
        /* To build directory if needed */
        bgv.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(bgv, "final22.jpg");

        try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        c.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
```

}

Is there is any problem with my code?

Please help...

thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you have the proper permissions?

Comment: I have given " <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />"

Comment: do i need to give more permissions?

Comment: nope, that is the permission for writing to the SD card. does the app crash? if yes, do you have the Logcat?

Comment: No the app doesn't crash,i have uploaded the picture of the preview i got on my galaxy S2 and the jpg image saved after the preview.please have a look  "http://www.flickr.com/photos/87489159@N06/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after lots of research on image processing i got my answer.
For Saving the jpg exactly same as what is drawn on canvas we have to add just two line of code.
First is :

`setDrawingCacheQuality(DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);`

and second in onDraw we have to set AntiAlias to true,refering to my code

```
paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
```

But after this also the saved image is not of same quality that of what is drawn on canvas.
to get the same crisp quality of image this two code will do the trick

```
paint1.setDither(true);
paint1.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Dither mainly provide smooth corners,AntiAlias,Dither and FilterBitmap can also be used while drawing Bitmap on canvas.

To get more information about Dither and AntiAlias here is the link

[AntiAlias](http://www.pantherproducts.co.uk/index.php?pageid=antialiasing)

[Dither](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/Support/FAQ/Article.aspx?name=How-To-Improve-Image-Quality)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the canvas's drawing cache may not be returning what you expect. You can blit directly to a bitmap using something like this:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap);
... draw your text, etc ...
```

Then save `myBitmap` to disk. Everything that you draw on the canvas should be drawn into the bitmap.

Comment: setBitmap() is not working.My app is getting crashed.
this is what I am getting in logcat
"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at android.view.HardwareCanvas.setBitmap(HardwareCanvas.java:37)
 "

Comment: Is your app requesting hardware acceleration in its manifest? If so, try disabling it. You might also try calling `invalidate()` in your original code after you're done drawing everything. In other words: draw, call `invalidate()`, and then save.

Comment: ,No luck :(
I don't know what but The Problem is with Typeface,because with android default fonts the final jpg is same as preview.

Comment: Very strange. Please edit your question to mention that fact about the Typeface. Someone else may have encountered that problem.